# Is it possible when adding an inputfile to show the filesize as text

Tags: apex, files, tag, apexinputfile

I have a simple inputfile tag. Is it possible to to show the filesize after selection

Visualforce

```
 <apex:inputFile id="inputfile" value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}"/><br/>
```

Something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                   $("[id$=inputfile]")[0].files[0].size;
                    </script>
```

Comment: You'd want do to this in JavaScript, since the value would no longer be valid after a file upload.

Comment: @sfdcfox How would I achieve this, I updated my question with what I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by handling the `onchange` event for the `apex:inputFile` element.

Update your `apex:inputFile` to add the handler and add a container to hold the size:

```
<apex:inputFile id="inputfile" value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}" onchange="handleFileChange(this)/>
Size: <span id="size"></span>
```

And then add a script to handle the event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var handleFileChange = function (input) {
        if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
            var size = input.files[0].size;
            document.getElementById("size").innerText = size;
        }
    }
</script>
```

When a file is selected, the handler will retrieve the size and set the text of the placeholder span to whatever the file size is.